# RDP from OS X to Windows using RD/TS Gateway Services?

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect from my Mac 10.8 to my work Terminal Services server. It think it runs Windows Server 2008. When using the RDC Client on **WinXP** ➞ **Win 8** it bring up these menu options:

[image]

You can see here it has the **computer** and the **username/domain** field. Then when I go to the **Advanced** field, I get the following:

[image]

When I open up [CORD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/), it is missing the option to put the **computer** name in the field. For **RDC** to my work network, I had the IT people look at both [CORD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) and [Microsoft RDC](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client) for OS X and they couldn't figure it out.

[image]

Can anyone shed light, based on those settings in my RDC (which is running on Windows 7 in a Parallels environment) how I could join to my network. Everyone says I need to be able to specify the following things:

1. URL to join *logon.tech2group.com.au*
2. Domain and Username *stream/danijel.james*
3. Computer name at the other end *rdfarm002*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the mappings from the MS RDP application to CoRD:

```
 MS RDP Field                          CoRD Field
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 Computer                              Address
 Domain part of your username          Domain (STREAM in your screen shots)
 Username part of your username        Username (danijel.james in your screen shots)
```

The RD Gateway server stuff isn't supported by CoRD though so you might be out of luck.  You can try RDP'ing to your RD Gateway (use `logon.tech2group.com.au` in the `Address` field in CoRD) and then RDP'ing from that machine in to another machine.

The only RDP application for OS X that I know of that supports RD Gateway/TS Gateway services is [iTap](http://itap-mobile.com/desktop/rdp). It's not free, it's $24.99, on the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itap-mobile-rdp/id498936621?mt=12). I haven't used it personally so I can't tell you if it's worth the money and supports RD Gateway the way it promises to.

Comment: I'll give it a look and see how I go. I spoke with someone else here, and they said the same thing - it needs the computer name, the IP or the URL, and the username with domain. So it must have either 3 fields with username/domain combined, or 4 fields specifying each. We can't RDP to any other computer in the domain unfortunately. It's setup specifically to be for our Windows 7 desktops, which I do not use personally on my desk anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, unless you are already a registered iTap user, it's no longer available as of October 8, 2013.  Microsoft's latest free version (8.0.3) does not support TS Gateway services.  I've been looking for something that does, but no luck so far.  Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's new version, v8.0.3, actually does support RD Gateways. I have just successfully made a connection through one today.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417